# Address only 15 bits of a WORD

Tags: c++, c++builder

Inside a class with several members of all sorts, I was hoping the following two variables would only take up 2 bytes together:

```
WORD wA:15
bool bB:1
```

I also tried `int` instead of `WORD`  ( `int wA:15` )

The intent is to let them only use 16 bits together.

Is there a way to achieve this ?
Doing bit operations in the code will mean changing the existing code.  I'm hoping I can do this by simply redefining the variables in the suggested way.

I use Borland C++ Builder 2009

Comment: And what problem do you have with the code you have shown?

Comment: By the way, unless you program for an embedded platform where the RAM size is in the kilobytes range instead of a modern PC with virtual memory in the gigabyte range, then do you really need to save a few bits (and making your program more complex in the process)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I want it to be 2 bytes only, to end of with an object that is 8 bytes smaller than it is now.  I have one boolean too many, so I end up with an 8 bytes bigger structure (I want it to be 8 bytes aligned).  I was hoping the combine the two variables in only 2 bytes as 15 bits is enough for the data in wA

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I end up loading millions of these objects in memory, I want to keep them as small as possible and still 8 byte aligned.

Comment: When you say "loading", I assume you load them from a file? Is it a binary file (where the structures are stored as-is)? If so, you should probably memory-map the file instead of loading the entries into heap-allocated memory. Then, unless the data is gigabytes and you're on a 32-bit system, you can get all data into memory anyway. And even if there's to much to fit into 32-bit address space you probably don't have to map the complete file, only a part of it.

Comment: In the future when asking questions, always state what *problem* you are trying to solve, not only say "I have this solution, help me make it work", without mentioning what problem you are trying to solve. There may be other solutions that may be better. Please read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, the **problem** is that I want those two variables to fit in 16 bits by properly declaring them.  The objects are interpreted btw., not raw data read from a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you must declare the same type for bit-packing
i.e.

```
WORD wA:15
WORD bB:1
```

but it may be platform specific..

for example, size of this structure is 2 like a size of type `short int`

```
struct test {
    short int a:15;
    short int b:1;
};
```

Comment: @RobKennedy In C++Builder XE5 with default options, `sizeof(struct test) == 2`. There are compiler options to change struct padding and so on.

Comment: You're right @EDkan, it works when I declare both variables as `unsigned int` (for instance)

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct your compiler to pack the structure with no padding:

```
#pragma pack
class { ...
```

Or

```
#pragma pack(1)
class { ...
```

Or

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
class { ...
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: I don't want to pack the entire class.  I did try the packing around the two variables, without success.  I also tried putting them in a sub structure of the class and put packing around that, without success.

Comment: What do you get if you define a struct with pragma pack and just those two members, and print sizeof(thestruct)?  Just a ten-line test program.

Comment: I get 4 bytes.  3 bytes if I byte pack the structure.

Comment: What is the size of `WORD`? And the size of `int`? Is it 2? Have you tried with `short int`?

Comment: @DidierTrosset, Will try `short int` tomorrow.  Not on my work station anymore.  PS. `WORD` is 2 bytes.

Comment: You should also try to define the members in the reverse order (with the bool first). There's nothing in the C nor C++ standard regarding how bit fields are organized in memory. It is compiler dependent. I'd also give a try to using `unsigned short int` for *both* members (It shouldn't hurt to have `unsigned short int` instead of `bool` when using it in other parts of your code).

Comment: @Peter Really weird, I tried it too and packed, and got 3 bytes.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky, indeed but two the same type variables does the trick.  My mistake was to assume that it worked across different type variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is all internal to the class, and the implementation isn't packing them the way you want, so why not do it yourself?

```
//typedef unsigned short WORD;
private:
    WORD twobytebuffer;
public:
    WORD getA() {return 0x7fff & twobytebuffer;}
    bool getB() {return (twobytebuffer>>15 == 1);}
```

Comment: I'm trying not to have to change the actual code, simply redefine the variables to achieve my aim (save 8 bytes on the object)